# How to fix SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, geolocation

I am getting an sql error when running the following code. I am a newbie to SQL. So please ignore if this is a silly question. Following is my SQL query to return some users based on their location

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.* FROM users u WHERE (u.id IN (SELECT id, 
                                            (6371 * acos( 
                                                        cos( radians(9.9894229) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(76.57897489999999) ) + sin( radians(9.9894229) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) 
                                                    ) 
                                            ) 
                                            AS distance 
                                            FROM users_geo_data 
                                            HAVING distance < 20
                                        )) ORDER BY u.time_created desc, u.id desc LIMIT 10
```

But I am getting error saying

SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

PS:

1. Because of the built in db architecture of the platform, I can use the radius search subquery only through a where clause.
2. Another thing is that I may have to order the search results based on distance (custom) or based on time_created (default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `IN` subquery returns more than one column.  So, move the distance calculate to a `where` clause:

```
u.id IN (SELECT id
         FROM users_geo_data 
         WHERE (6371 * acos( 
                            cos( radians(9.9894229) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(76.57897489999999) ) + sin( radians(9.9894229) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) < 20
       )
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the fix. That worked. But what to do if I want to order the users based on the distance calculated?

Comment: @mohammedaqeel . . . That would be a very different question and should be asked as a *new* question.  You wouldn't be able to do that by filtering in the `where` clause.  You would need to use a `JOIN` or correlated subquery.

Comment: Gordon, thank you. As I told in my main question, because of the particular architecture of the platform database, I cant do a JOIN clause. previously I used to do that with the same query and then ordered by distance. 

Can you help me with the correlated subquery? thanks in advance.